# Use Kubernetes secret under Helm File

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helmfile

Had Kubernetes secret file in cluster of type opaque which has base64 encoded values. How to use this file to refer secrets in helm file which pulls helm chart for deployment?

Below is my helm file format

```
bases: 
- ../environments.yaml
- ../defaults.yaml
releases:
- name: {{ env "AST" | default "astenv" }}-appname
  chart: HelmChart_Name
  version: 1.0
  labels: 
    tier: configData
    service: webapp
  namespace: {{ .Namespace }}
  values:
  - ../../values/common.gotmpl
```

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions) and introduces this as an example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  token: |-
    {{ .Files.Get "config1.toml" | b64enc }}
```

Comment: Need to check by implementing this. Thank you

Comment: Did you had time to check it? :)